# jquery dynamically loaded dialog not closing

Tags: jquery

I have encountered one issue and not sure about its origin. I have the following dialog with dynamically loaded content:

```
$(function(){   
    $('.dialog_link_check_interval').click(function(){          
        var link = this;

        var link_id = link.id.split('-');
        link_id = link_id[1];

        $('#dialog_check_interval').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 650,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                'OK': function() {                      
                    var check_interval_new = $('#check_interval_new').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'file.php',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: 'property_id=' + link_id + '&check_interval=' + check_interval_new,
                    });

                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });

        $('#dialog_check_interval').load('dialog_generator.php?link_id=' + link_id).dialog('open'); 
    });     
});
```

and HTML

```
<div id='dialog_check_interval' title='Check interval' style='display: none;'></div>    
<div id='check_interval-123' class='dialog_link_check_interval'>
   <a href='#' style='border:0'>dialog link</a>
</div>
```

In dynamically loaded dialog_generator.php there is text input with id=check_interval_new. I have found that if check_interval_new is deleted from javascript, then the dialog is closing as expected. However, when there is check_interval_new, the dialog is not closing (but the value is correctly retrieved from dialog_generator.php as I have found with the alert function) upon clicking on "OK" button (but closing with hitting ESC or by clicking on X in the right top corner).

Note that I have tried various other functions than `$(this).dialog('close');` to close dialog such as `$('#dialog_check_interval').dialog('close');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to $.ajax is not correctly formed. Should be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      property_id: link_id,
      check_interval: check_interval_new,
    }
});
```

That's at least one issue I spot.

===== EDIT =====

Also, check what you are getting in the browser console.

===== EDIT 2 =====

Just to flesh out one of my comments:

```
var the_dialog = $('#dialog_check_interval');
the_dialog.dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 650,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    'OK': function() {                      
       var check_interval_new = $('#check_interval_new').val();

       $.ajax({
         url: 'file.php',
         type: 'GET',
         data: {
           property_id: link_id,
           check_interval: check_interval_new,
         } 
       }).success(function () {
         // consider adding a success function
       }).error(function () {
         // consider adding an error function
       });
       the_dialog.dialog('close');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. That syntax is maybe not correct but amending it did not help me. Upon clicking "OK", Firebug reports nothing.

Comment: Ok. I just checked your code (unchanged) on my end, and the "OK" button is closing the dialog on my end. However, I of course don't have your server response. So, have you checked what going on by opening the browser console? Also, make sure that your jquery.js and jquery.ui.js match.  I tried this with jquery 1.9.1 and jquery.ui 1.10.3.

Comment: Just to let you know that I am not able to recreate your problem. I have tried the  $('#dialog_check_interval').load(... with various tests on my end, but the close is always behaving correctly. What exactly is your dialog_generator.php returning?

Comment: That is strange. I tried to recreate it with jsfiddle but there it is working (but obviously without external page dialog_generator.php). Console is saying the following (upon clicking "OK" button): `Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'`. Really don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Ok, then I am pretty sure that it has something to do with what dialog_generator.php is returning. I've actually tried scenarios where dialog_generator.php returns a new element with the id of the dialog, but that doesn't stop the OK handler from working correctly. Maybe you should try something like this: `var the_dialog = $('#dialog_check_interval'); the_dialog.dialog(<your current dialog initialization code>);` except instead of `$(this).dialog('close');` you would have `the_dialog.dialog('close');`.  Hope it is clear what I have in mind :)

Comment: I do not know why but your code is working perfectly! OK button is closing my dialog as expected!

Comment: So, I guess I should update my answer with the suggestion from my latest comment. Well, your browser complains about missing "prior initialization", and my latest change simply stores a reference to the initial initialization. That variable is then visible in the scope of the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like missing event delegation. since you are using a dynamically injected dialog, you should bind the event to a parent that exists when the element was inserted.

[Delegation in jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: I went through the article but still not sure how to amend my code.

Comment: alternatively, you could add a success: function(e){
   //code here
},
error: function(xhr, status, error){
console.log(error);
}
 to your ajax call

Comment: Yes, I second that. You would probably want to keep the dialog open if there was an error in ajax call. Close it on success. Or isn't that how you would like to have this?

Comment: Ajax call is working properly. Only thing that does not work is closing the dialog when hitting "OK" button. Ajax is therefore not throwing any error.